# 2D Array Matrix; Reading Diagonals

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, diagonal

I am attempting to write a method for a 5x5 matrix that gives the output:
00004
00030
00200
01000
00000

My output for this specific code is:
40000
03000
00200
00010
00000

Essentially I am attempting to read the array from right to left rather than left to right. 
My parameters are that I can only use a single for loop and cannot hardcode the values within the method.

Is there any way I can make a simple change to accomplish this?

```
 private static void fillDiagonal_2( int[][] m )
 {
            for (int row=0; row<m.length; ++row)
            {   
                m[row][row]=row;
                System.out.print(m[row][row]);
            }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int row = 0; row < m.length; ++row)
{   
    m[row][m.length - row] = row;
    System.out.print(m[row][row]);
}
```

That should work.

edit:
You should declare a variable outside of the for loop so you don't recall m.length every time.

```
int length = m.length - 1;

   for (int row = 0; row <= length; ++row)
   {   
     m[row][length - row] = row;
     System.out.print(m[row][row]);
   }
```

Try that.

Comment: I receive an exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: }
catch( Exception e )
{
 System.out.println("EXCEPTION CAUGHT: " + e );
 System.exit(0);
}

Comment: This is my fault. I rushed it. This is caused because you start an array at 0 to length - 1; 

if there are 5 objects you can only reference the objects by using 0 - 4 correct?

I edited my answer. Enjoy. 

Also, don't post up homework questions on here. There are many people who will turn you in before helping you. This is a simple concept answer, and I already started helping but be warned.

Comment: Thanks so much. Tremendous help, had been sitting with this for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int len = m.length;
for (int i = 0; i < (len * len); i++) {
    System.out.print(m[i / len][len - (i % len) - 1]);
}
```

Example:

```
int m[][] = new int[][]{{0, 0, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 0, 0, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

Output:

```
4000003000002000001000000
```

It works by associating each index `i` to a position in the matrix `m` using the length:

```
i -> m[i / len][len - (i % len) - 1]
0 -> m[   0   ][      len - 1      ]
1 -> m[   0   ][      len - 2      ]
2 -> m[   0   ][      len - 3      ]
3 -> m[   0   ][      len - 1      ]
4 -> m[   0   ][      len - 1      ]
5 -> m[   1   ][      len - 1      ]
6 -> m[   1   ][      len - 2      ]
7 -> m[   1   ][      len - 3      ]
...
```